# How to set the distance between to subfigures each with a tikz-pic inside?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

My code is as follows. I want to increase the distance between the two diagrams:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table}{xcolor}

\documentclass [11pt,a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,matrix,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\subfigure[Before]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,
  >=stealth',
  shorten >=1pt,
  auto,
  node distance=3cm,
  thick,
  main node/.style={
              circle,
              fill=RoyalBlue!90!green!80,
              draw,
              font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
 ]
  \node[main node,label=below:Cause]             (y)  {$Y$};
  \node[main node,label=below:Effect,right of=y] (x)  {$X$};
  \node[above=1cm of x]                              (nx) {$N_X$};
  \node[above=1cm of y]                              (ny) {$N_Y$};

  \path (y)  edge[right] node[below right,font=\sffamily\small] {} (x);
%  \path (x)  edge[bend right,orange]node[above,font=\sffamily\small,orange]{}(y);
  \path (nx) edge[blue] node[left,font=\sffamily\small,orange] {} (x);
  \path (ny) edge[blue] (y);
\end{tikzpicture}\label{fig:FCM}
%\caption{General Functional Causal Model for two 1D variables}
}
\subfigure[After]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,
  >=stealth',
  shorten >=1pt,
  auto,
  node distance=3cm,
  thick,
  main node/.style={
              circle,
              fill=RoyalBlue!90!green!80,
              draw,
              font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
 ]
  \node[main node,label=below:Cause]             (y)  {$Y$};
  \node[main node,label=below:Effect,right of=y] (x)  {$X$};

  \path (y)  edge[right] node[below right,font=\sffamily\small] {$\varphi$} (x);
  \path (x)  edge[bend right,orange] node[above,font=\sffamily\small,color=orange] {$\varphi^{-1}$} (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\PassOptionsToPackage?` It's rarely needed in that form. And `subfigure` has been obsolete for several years: use `subfig` or `subcaption`.

Comment: Your example code won't compile; you didn't load the `subfigure` package and there's a spurious `\begin{tikzpicture}[->,` line just after `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Between the two `subfigure`s, you can use `\quad`, `\qquad`, `\hspace{<length>}` (where `<length>` is any valid length) or, even, `\hfill`:

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper] {article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,matrix,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\subfigure[Before]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,
  >=stealth',
  shorten >=1pt,
  auto,
  node distance=3cm,
  thick,
  main node/.style={
              circle,
              fill=RoyalBlue!90!green!80,
              draw,
              font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
 ]
  \node[main node,label=below:Cause]             (y)  {$Y$};
  \node[main node,label=below:Effect,right of=y] (x)  {$X$};
  \node[above=1cm of x]                              (nx) {$N_X$};
  \node[above=1cm of y]                              (ny) {$N_Y$};

  \path (y)  edge[right] node[below right,font=\sffamily\small] {} (x);
%  \path (x)  edge[bend right,orange]node[above,font=\sffamily\small,orange]{}(y);
  \path (nx) edge[blue] node[left,font=\sffamily\small,orange] {} (x);
  \path (ny) edge[blue] (y);
\end{tikzpicture}\label{fig:FCM}
%\caption{General Functional Causal Model for two 1D variables}
}\hfill
\subfigure[After]
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,
  >=stealth',
  shorten >=1pt,
  auto,
  node distance=3cm,
  thick,
  main node/.style={
              circle,
              fill=RoyalBlue!90!green!80,
              draw,
              font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
 ]
  \node[main node,label=below:Cause]             (y)  {$Y$};
  \node[main node,label=below:Effect,right of=y] (x)  {$X$};

  \path (y)  edge[right] node[below right,font=\sffamily\small] {$\varphi$} (x);
  \path (x)  edge[bend right,orange] node[above,font=\sffamily\small,color=orange] {$\varphi^{-1}$} (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `subfigure` is an obsolote package; you should use `subcaption` or `subfig` instead. Notice also that you can load `xcolor` with your options *before* `tikz` in the standard way, so you don't have to use `\PassOptionsToPackage`.